# toggle multiple divs of the same class using checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, closest, toggleclass

I have a set of divs with the same class. Inside each div is an identical list of checkboxes. These checkboxes connect to jquery function to toggle the div to a different class. But currently when you click a checkbox rather then just changing that one div it changes all the divs. I'm trying to get it, so that each div responds individually to the checkboxes inside itself.

You can see what I'm talking about here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dustinohara/3nK5A/180/

This is for a gallery system I'm working on, where each div will have an image and the checkboxes will be used to assign class names that will then be used for filtering with the isotope plugin.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `$(this)` in your event handler. [Fixed jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nK5A/182/)

Answer (score 0):

use the magic word $(this).

here the code

```
$(".editCHECK").change(function() {

    $(this).closest('.box').toggleClass("edit");

});


$(".adCHECK").change(function() {

    $(this).closest('.box').toggleClass("ad");

});


$(".personalCHECK").change(function() {

    $(this).closest('.box').toggleClass("personal");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".editCHECK, .adCHECK, .personalCHECK").change(function() {
 $(this).closest('.box').toggleClass($(this).attr('class').replace('CHECK', ''));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nK5A/183/)